# GridPane with gaps inside ScrollPane rendering wrong

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane, gridpane

I want to have a rectangular grid with square cells, which can be zoomed and dragged (like you would a map). So I put it in a ScrollPane, altough it behaves rather weirdly at certain sizes. The size of the grid will change dynamically.

On the picture there is a grid of size 20x20.
[image: Grid of size 20x20]

1. **Not all gaps are shown inside the grid.** Notice that it should be 20 squares
   but isn't. Both Vgap and Hgap is 1.
2. **The grid itself is larger than the content**, which is not good, because when it will be zoomed I could drag beyond the border of the grid.
3. I would like to **center the GridPane inside the ScrollPane** when it is smaller than the scrollpane. (`Gridpane alignment="CENTER"` is apparently not doing anything)

---

### Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER" hvalue="0.5" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" pannable="true" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" vbarPolicy="NEVER" vvalue="0.5" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="bug.app.Bug">
    <GridPane fx:id="gridPane" alignment="CENTER" hgap="1.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" vgap="1.0">
    </GridPane>
</ScrollPane>
```

Controller + Main:

```
package bug.app;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Bug extends Application {
    private static final int HEIGHT = 20;
    private static final int WIDTH = 20;
    private static final double MIN_CELL_SIZE = 2;
    @FXML private GridPane gridPane;
    private DoubleProperty zoomRatio = new SimpleDoubleProperty(5);

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        final DoubleBinding cellSizeBinding = zoomRatio.multiply(MIN_CELL_SIZE);

        List<Node> cells = new ArrayList<>(HEIGHT * WIDTH);
        for (int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++) {
                final Pane cell = new Pane();
                cell.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.YELLOW, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

                cell.setMinSize(MIN_CELL_SIZE, MIN_CELL_SIZE);
                cell.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
                cell.setMaxHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
                cell.prefWidthProperty().bind(cellSizeBinding);
                cell.prefHeightProperty().bind(cellSizeBinding);

                GridPane.setConstraints(cell, col, row, 1, 1);

                cells.add(cell);
            }
        }
        gridPane.getChildren().clear();
        gridPane.getChildren().addAll(cells);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(
                getClass().getResource("/view/bugView.fxml"));
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

**NB:** I chose a Pane as a Cell because I want to subclass it and eventually fill it (with probably Shapes?) with different colours dividing the square into 1-4 parts. Imagine two or four triangles forming a square. I would also like to resize this elegantly (AFAIK Shapes are not resizable), maybe somehow binding the size of the inner Shapes to the Panes' size will do the magic. I am not that far yet, but feel free to advise on this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problems 1 & 2

I found a workaround for issues **1.** and **2.** with omitting Vgap and Hgap, because apparently it is buggy.

Instead of using the gap property of the GridPane I set the margin on each cell:

```
GridPane.setMargin(cell, new Insets(0.5));
```

This however rounds the margin to 1 because of the default `snapToPixel="true"` on GridPane and thus resulting to gaps of 2px. This is unconvenient, because I want the squares to be as small as 2x2px, so the 2px gap is too much. I shall probably set `snapToPixel` to `false` on the GridPane. Needs more testing.

### Problem 3

<s>I tried wrapping the GridPane in a StackPane as suggested by @Silas Gyeme.</s>

Simply wrapping it in a StackPane was not enough. I had to set both `fitToHeight="true"` & `fitToWidth="true"` on the ScrollPane.

Also had to bind the cell's minSize to cellSizeBinding, because it was resizing the squares when I shrinked the window smaller.

```
cell.minWidthProperty().bind(cellSizeBinding);
cell.minHeightProperty().bind(cellSizeBinding);
```

**EDIT:** I tried omitting the StackPane and I do not actually need it! Only setting `fitToHeight` and `fitToWidth` is enough, the GridPane will stretch well.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the gridpane inside a stackpane, this will center the gridpane

Comment: Simply wrapping it in a StackPane was not enough. I had to set both `fitToHeight="true"` & `fitToWidth="true"` and also binding the cell's minSize to cellSizeBinding.
However you do not address the more important issues and your answer about the centering was not complete, so I would not accept it.